# python requests scrape with post and fill a form from drop-down menu

Tags: python, forms, post, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to **scrape** this page:

http://www.barb.co.uk/viewing-data/weekly-top-30/

I'm trying to fill the form, with this data:

```
station=BBC2 (SD+HD)
year=2016
month=January
week=11 Jan - 17 Jan
```

So this is what I tried:

```
import requests
import json
url='http://www.barb.co.uk/viewing-data/weekly-top-30/'
payload= {
    'station[]':['2'],
    'period_year[]':  ['2016'],        
    'period_month[]': ['1'],
    'period_week[]': ['201601060117']                    
}
session=requests.session()
r=requests.post(url,data=payload)
with open ('html_res.html','w') as f:
    f.write(str(r.content))
```

In `html_res.html` I don't get the desired data.
I wonder what I'm doing wrong.
Thanks.

Comment: when I try in my browser, the request is going to http://barb-api.mediatel.co.uk//whats-new/weekly-top-30 and the response is json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code.

```
import requests
import json

headers = {
    'Origin': 'http://www.barb.co.uk',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8,he;q=0.6',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Referer': 'http://www.barb.co.uk/viewing-data/weekly-top-30/',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
}

data = [
  ('method', 'POST'),
  ('station[]', '839'),
  ('period[]', '201710060108'),
]

r = requests.post('http://barb-api.mediatel.co.uk//whats-new/weekly-top-30', headers=headers, data=data)
print(json.dumps(r.json(),indent=2))
```

You can use [this](https://curl.trillworks.com/) website to convert curl to python code.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same in several ways. Here is a concise one:

```
import requests

payload={
'method':'POST','station[]':'2','period[]':'201601060117'
}

page = requests.post("http://barb-api.mediatel.co.uk//whats-new/weekly-top-30", params=payload)
for item in page.json():
    data = item['data']['201601060117']
    for name in data:
        print(name['programme_name'],name['data_value'],name['28_days_total'])
```

Partial results:

```
UNIVERSITY CHALLENGE (MON 2001) 3.13 3.14
TRUST ME  I'M A DOCTOR (WED 2000) 3.01 3.16
ONLY CONNECT (MON 2031) 2.7 2.75
VICTORIAN BAKERS (TUE 2001) 2.69 2.73
SNOOKER (SUN 1901) 2.11 2.12
```